# Особенности работы  приложения  на конкретном устройстве

Tags: eclipse, android, java, эмулятор

Всем привет!
Проверял работу приложения на разных девайсах. Все было ок, ну кое-где свои нюансики, но в целом всё нормально.
И вот, как говорится, ищущий нашел :)

1-е. Sony Xperia E-dual

Всё работает, за исключением одного. В статусбаре висит уведомление проги, по клику на которое должно вылезать основное активити приложения - так оно на других аппаратах и происходит. Так вот на соньке есть, так сказать, "дополнительная" фича :). Прога работает в фоне, уведомление в статусбаре. Теперь!! если качнуть устройством в любую сторону, то возникает событие аналогичное клику на уведомлении, и соответственно на передний план выскакивает основное активити приложения. Я так понимаю это срабатывает датчик положения девайса в пространстве, но с какого .... его событие получается эквивалентным событию клика по уведомлению??
Кто может подсказать, что происходит и как побороть?

2-е. HTC desire.

Тут вообще полный кошмар. Графика вся становится кривой. Ну это ещё как=то можно побороть
Но зато отказывается работать половина функционала приложения, связанная с доступом к бд и управлением телефонией. Это просто кошмар какой-то, что это за аппарат такой???
Тут вопрос  - есть ли максимально приближенные эмуляторы данного девайса, которые можно подрубить к эклипсу, где их достать? :) Ибо сам телефон не у меня и работать с ним непосредственно возможности нет.

Comment: ОСи на девайсах одни и те же?

Comment: что на соне что на хтц 4-й андроид.

до этого проверял и на 2-м и на 4-м на разных других девайсах включая полные ноунеимы из кетая... везде есть свою нюансы, но не критично. в целом работоспособность сохраняется.
самая .опа - это на хтц, где вообще можно сказать прога дышать отказывается...
для начала хотя бы с сонькой разобраться, что там за байда от датчика идёт, поднимающая активити....

Comment: @Demon051 4-й это ни о чем. Для Киткат (4.4) есть серьезные изменения по телефонии и доступу к БД. Потрудитесь, бро, дать конкретную версию...

Comment: на хтц могу сказать точно 4.0.3 на соне только к вечеру узнать могу. :(
но на соне в общем=то тока с уведомлением криво

Comment: графика у Вас разлезлась по одной простой причине (хотелось конечно бы скриншот увидеть). Графику и лайауты оно собирает с разных каталогов. Скорее всего, для HTC desire выбирается специфичный лайаут (не тот, который Вы ожидаете). В свое время имел похожую проблему (на googleTV) - решил просто - в эмуляторе подобрал правильные параметры (размеры/разрешение), добился эффекта и потом "подсветил лайауты" - то есть, сделал так, что бы однотипные лайауты и картинки были немного разные и можно было бы различить их.

А вот с Sony... может у человека пользовательский глючный лаунчер?

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать в чем причина... Скорее всего что приходит на ум причины могут быть:

1. Сборка производится под старшей версией Андроида, и у вас где-то используются функции API недоступные под ранними версиями. Пересоберите под версией Андроида с наиболее низким уровнем API - обычно это помогает.
2. По графике - [best practice](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence) - как создавать приложение поддерживаемое разными разрешениями.
3. Возможно в качестве элементов UI используются картинки с хардкодированными разрешениями или отступами/лейаутами. Первый признак, того что у вас что-то не так если в лейаутах используются абсолютные значения типа `android:size=10px` - `px` это некошерно, надо или `dp` или `sp`

Полезно также попробовать поиграться с [Android Compatibility Test Suite](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html)

Comment: Собираю я с указанием targedapi 7 . Это андроид 2.1. Оно и работает на целевой платформе и выше без проблем - за исключением описанного случая. Никакой суперграфики. Стандартные лэйауты, обычные png. Никаких px. В общем щас даже больше интересует что за событие от датчика на сони, вызывающее вывод главного активити приложения.

Comment: Указание target'а недостаточно. Гораздо более важно под какой версией SDK вы собираете?

Comment: В манифесте targetSdkVersion = 7 что как бы тоже соответствует 2.1. В самом проекте правда тянется либа support-v4. Это как раз для поддержки билдера нотификаций...
Или я опять не про то? :) 
На соньке 4.1.1 андроид.
Щас вот попробовал другой аппарат с 4.1.1 - все пашет без проблем. Чудны дела твои..

Comment: @Demon051 да не об этом речь! Под какой версией Android SDK собираешь! Не `targetSdk`, а `android.jar` от какой версии SDK цепляется?! Или вы вообще не в курсе что это такое?

*Млеать - девелоперы пошли...*

Comment: Либа суппорта кстати, [также зависит](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) от версии Android SDK, но это походу уже слишком сложно :))

Comment: Ну я скажем так и не джава девелопер. Балуюсь для себя. Завтра посмотрю чо там где цепляется.

Comment: Ну понятно тогда все, а то я думал чукча писатель. Но раз назвался груздём - так и не отнекивайся и учи матчасть!

Comment: Вобще, Бармалей, как это ни странно, но цепляется из папочки
...\android-sdks\platforms\android-7\android.jar :)
Так что не надо меня путать. Я уж сомневаться вчера стал. Помню вроде, что для 2.1. по умолчанию всё создавал и ничего после этого не менял.